# How to reload Gallery image when Setting default option Product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

My point is when Go to the Product page (configurable Product), the product will load the first option automatically.
When trying to do it I had trouble loading new image for the first option and I found that the gallery has not loaded in first time. Could anybody help me to check this function?

In this file `Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this issue.
Thanks.